# How can I override .hgrc options on the command line?

Tags: configuration, mercurial, overriding

I typically want to ignore white space changes when diff'ing with mercurial. If I set this as a default by putting `ignorews = true` in my .hgrc's [diff] section then there doesn't seem to be a way to force the display of white space changes for a single invocation on the command line. What am I missing?

FWIW: None of the relevant command line options accepts an argument. Using the (deprecated) `[defaults]` section has the same behavior. I'm assuming the final answer will be "use an alias for ignoring space", but am hopeful something better exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `hg(1)` man page:

```
   --config
          set/override config option (use 'section.name=value')
```

Comment: Do you have any example for that option? I tried `hg --config defaults.glog="<something>"` but it doesn't work. Just print the help for basic commands. The `.hgrc` is not changed.

Comment: Text editor is fine. Everything works. But I think the question here is how to override it from `command line`

Comment: @EnzoChi: You can override the config file with `--config`. You cannot use `--config` to write to the config file.