# In mercurial is there a way to tell hg log and diff to skip binary diffs?

Tags: mercurial, diff, binaryfiles

If I'm combing through diffs using `hg log -p` or `hg diff`, it would be nice to see something like "binary file differs", rather than having to scroll through screenfulls of gibberish to get to the next file.  Is there a configuration trick to do that?

(On preview, if there's no simple `hg` option to set, then there might be some hints in the right direction in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015542/getting-readable-diff-displays-in-mercurial-on-unicode-files-ms-windows).  I would still need more help to get what I'm asking, though.)

Comment: could you please give a list of steps to reproduce a minimal example? currently tried and don't see such gibberish, just a line stating "Binary file some.blob has changed"

Comment: I want what you've got!  When I have a changeset that changes a pdf, for instance, then either `hg log -pr` or `hg diff --change` are giving me output like: `GIT binary patch — literal 467997 — zc%0O_1#lcqvMxHZ(3UJ_mc6W7...` _(many lines)_

Comment: There's a `-a` / `--text` option to force text output, if something is accidentally detected as binary, but the reverse doesn't seem to be provided.  And I just learned binary detection is [based on the presense of NUL bytes in the file.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BinaryFiles)  My pdf definitely has some strings of NUL bytes in it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With @arhak's help, I see the problem was this in my `.hgrc`

```
[diff]
git = True
```

I'd forgotten that I'd added that after reading [this advice](http://hgtip.com/tips/beginner/2009-10-22-always-use-git-diffs/) that git-style diffs are more readable than the patch-style diffs that are Mercurial's default.  I can't find a description of the differences, but looking at a few diffs now, `--git` (`-g`) seems to leave out dates in the filename headers, and apparently, it also forces the full uuencode-style diff for binary files.  I think I'll keep it as default, but turn it off if for the unusual situations where I'm looking at patches with lots of binary file changes.

To [override at the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310658/how-can-i-override-hgrc-options-on-the-command-line) without editing `.hgrc`, add `--config diff.git=False`

I'd be curious if there's a way to skip the binaries, but keep git formatting for the regular text files in the diff.

Answer (score 2):

this is what I get, check mercurial version, just in case

I'm thinking perhaps you have an extensions making fancy stuff with blobs, since I can't get what you describe. I just get `Binary file doc.pdf has changed`

```
$ hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.9.2)
...
$ mkdir hg-test
$ cd hg-test
$ hg init
$ echo a text line > text.txt
$ hg add text.txt
$ hg commit -m "1st"
$ echo another text line >> text.txt
$ hg commit -m "2nd"
$ hg add doc.pdf
$ hg commit -m "a binary file"
$ hg commit -m "modified the binary file"
$ hg diff --change 3
diff -r 2fd7730bc3bb -r 155aefdccfbe doc.pdf
Binary file doc.pdf has changed
$ hg diff --change 1
diff -r 9e171966ad0d -r 105aa77984c0 text.txt
--- a/text.txt  Sat Dec 17 12:18:46 2016 +0100
+++ b/text.txt  Sat Dec 17 12:19:28 2016 +0100
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 a text line
+another text line
$ hg log -pr0:3
changeset:   0:9e171966ad0d
user:        arhak
date:        Sat Dec 17 12:18:46 2016 +0100
summary:     1st

diff -r 000000000000 -r 9e171966ad0d text.txt
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/text.txt  Sat Dec 17 12:18:46 2016 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+a text line

changeset:   1:105aa77984c0
user:        arhak
date:        Sat Dec 17 12:19:28 2016 +0100
summary:     2nd

diff -r 9e171966ad0d -r 105aa77984c0 text.txt
--- a/text.txt  Sat Dec 17 12:18:46 2016 +0100
+++ b/text.txt  Sat Dec 17 12:19:28 2016 +0100
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 a text line
+another text line

changeset:   2:2fd7730bc3bb
user:        arhak
date:        Sat Dec 17 12:27:38 2016 +0100
summary:     a binary file

diff -r 105aa77984c0 -r 2fd7730bc3bb doc.pdf
Binary file doc.pdf has changed

changeset:   3:155aefdccfbe
tag:         tip
user:        arhak
date:        Sat Dec 17 12:28:50 2016 +0100
summary:     modified the binary file

diff -r 2fd7730bc3bb -r 155aefdccfbe doc.pdf
Binary file doc.pdf has changed
```

Comment: Thanks! I was a point you behind in my hg version — but updating didn't help.  Based on your thinking, though, I tried `mv .hgrc .hgrc.bak` and with default configurations I *do* get "Binary file... has changed".  I'll try to follow up after I narrow down to the culprit.